# <g:layoutBody /> does not render the styling applied to <body> tag

Tags: css, html, grails, layout, sitemesh

I've created a simple layout using grails default layout pattern.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title><g:layoutTitle default="my website" /></title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css" />

        <g:layoutHead />
            <r:layoutResources />

    </head>
    <body id="mainContainer">

        <g:render template="/templates/headerTemplate"></g:render>
        <g:render template="/templates/menuTemplate"></g:render>
        <g:layoutBody />
        <r:layoutResources />

    </body>
</html>
```

Now so far as I understand the <g:layoutBody /> renders the body content. (Please correct me if I'm mistaken). Now I've applied custom styling to the <body> tag of each pages. But that **styling is not being applied to my rendered view**. Eg. I've an image which I want to apply to the body. But that is not being applied. When I insert a div inside the body and apply the same image to it, its getting applied to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="mainLayout"/>
    <title>Match List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir:'js',file:'matchDetailsJS.js')}"></script>
</head>
<body class="myclass">    </body>
</html>
```

My css file is getting included as my styling is being applied to other elements.

What am I missing? Is something wrong with my g:layout? I tried finding in the documentation but so far did'nt find anything much.
Let me know if my question is not clear.
Thanking you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because the layout needs to understand you have properties that you wish to supply for the body tag. The [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html) has a good example about using page property to specify an onload attribute of the body tag.

Here is the example modified for your needs.

### layout

```
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="my website" /></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css" />

    <g:layoutHead />
        <r:layoutResources />

</head>
<body id="mainContainer" class="${pageProperty(name:'body.class')">

    <g:render template="/templates/headerTemplate"></g:render>
    <g:render template="/templates/menuTemplate"></g:render>
    <g:layoutBody />
    <r:layoutResources />

</body>
```

Comment: I used the `${pageProperty(name:'body.class')` and `${pageProperty(name:'body.onload')`. But this has increased my page load time. Why so? I've used jQuery & also javascript.

Comment: I think that's a new question to be asked, and when you do ask make sure you post what you are doing in your pages as well as your layout. It would also be helpful if you indicate in the post how you are measuring the load time of the pages.